# Where to insert MathJax to show the latex equation

Tags: html, mathjax

Hi I am a beginner for HTML, and here is the main part of my code for the index.html.

```
 <div class="row">
            {% endif %}
                <div class="4u">
    <span class="MathJax_Preview" style="color: inherit; display: none;"></span>
                    <section class="box">
                        {% if article.picture is defined %}
                        <a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ article.url }}" class="image image-full"><img src="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ article.picture }}" alt=""/></a>
                        {% endif %}
                        <header>
                            <h3>{{article.title }}</h3>
                            <span class="byline">{{ article.date }}</span>
                        </header>
                        {{ article.summary }}
                        <footer class="actions">
                            <a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ article.url }}" class="button button-icon button-icon-1">Continue Reading</a>
                        </footer>
                    </section>
                </div>
            {% if loop.index % 3  == 0 %}
            </div>
```

The output of my code is :

[image]

As shown in the picture, some of the latex equation cannot be recognized. I know I could use MathJax to render them, but seems I did not insert to a right place.

Any idea how I could fix this ?

Comment: I retagged since this is not a latex question :) Can you please post a minimal code, complete with header, or better a JsFiddle? Thank you.

Comment: Dear @MattAllegro, thanks for your suggestion. Forgive me I don't quite understand your comment here, do you mean I need to post other part of the codes like css file? Or do you mean I should post the header in the chrome page source?

Comment: A fiddle with images, css and `<head>` would help a lot!! http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve